# Return array of values from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, mysqli, while-loop

I wanted to make a while function similar to WordPress with the have_posts() function that it uses in a custom application I'm building. I might be missing something simple but I have a database with a table called clients.

Within clients is some client information that is pull from the database via my function clients().

I have about 10 columns in the client table, in this example only five of them are actually in use (have any data in them).

Now in my function I have the following

```
function clients() {

$getclients = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM clients") or die(mysqli_error($sql));

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($getclients) >= 1) {

        $clientsdata = mysqli_fetch_array($getclients);
        $clientrows = mysqli_num_rows($clientsdata);

        return $clientsdata;

    } else {

        return;

    }

}
```

Now in my HTML, I have the following:

```
    <?php $maxrows = 10; ?>
    <?php $currentrows = 0; ?>
    <?php while ( ( get_clients( "", "", "", "" ) ) && ( $currentrows < $maxrows ) ) : ?>

        <?php echo $clientsdata['1']; ?> <?php echo $clientsdata['2']; ?>
        <?php var_dump($clientsdata); ?>

        <?php $currentrows++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now the only thing being outputted on my page is **NULL** ten times which is to do with the while loop limit which is set to ten as it looped five times when changed to five etc.

Now my aim to to have a while loop that lets me print out the client data for each row there is in the database. However this just doesn't seem to be working at all and can't see why my function isn't returning anything.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: That function only fetches one row at a time. You need to loop it or fetchall. `Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both`. - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You'll need to include more code here; you're looping based on the results of `get_clients()` but aren't telling us what it is. Are you sure there's data in your database? And why are you outputting the same values 10 times?

Comment: `$clientsdata` is only in the `clients` function's scope.

Comment: `$clientsdata` does not exists with data anywhere except within the function and i don't see any `$clientsdata = clients()` in the code you are showing. i can only say you do not know enough about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I really don't understand to be honest. I'm trying to just get all the client data from the clients table. Then essentially say `while myfunction() { display values }` but I have no idea how to do that. I essentially would like something similiar to how WordPress handles it but I couldn't find anything on how it does it.

Comment: First off, if you only want 10 results, put a limit on the query, then use a foreach loop in php to display.